# Prevent user from entering whitespace in Java

Tags: java

I want the user to only enter his age. So I did this program :

```
Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);  
int age;

while(!keyb.hasNextInt())
{
    keyb.next();
    System.out.println("How old are you ?");
}

age = keyb.nextInt();
System.out.println("you are" + age + "years old");
```

I found how to prevent user from using string by using the while loop with keyb.hasNextInt(), but how to prevent him from using the whitespace or from entering more input than his age ?

For example I want to prevent this kind of typing "12 m" or "12 12"

Also, how can I clear all existing data in the buffer ? I'm facing an infinite loop when I try to use this :

```
while(keyb.hasNext())
  keyb.next();
```

Comment: Read the whole line instead, then check the format of the input. If it's not what you want, ask for the input again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the default behaviour of `Scanner` is to use any whitespace as the delimiter. This includes spaces. This means that `a 3 a` is in fact three tokens, not one. You can change the delimiter to a new line so that `a 3 a` becomes a single token, which will then return false for `hasNextInt`.

I've also added an initial question, because in your example the first input was taken before asking any questions.

```
Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
keyb.useDelimiter("\n"); // You can try System.lineSeparator() but it didn't work in IDEA
int age;

System.out.println("How old are you?");
while(!keyb.hasNextInt())
{
    keyb.next();
    System.out.println("No really. How old are you?");
}

age = keyb.nextInt();
System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old");
```

Comment: I learned a lot from your reply, thank you ! I'm wondering though, if I want to go back to the default delimiter, I just have to type keyb.useDelimiter(" "), is that right ?

Comment: @Spn Not quite. "Any whitespace" is not limited only to spaces, it also includes tabs, new lines, etc. To revert back to exactly as it was before, you can use `"\\p{javaWhitespace}+"`. But don't do that - you can simply call [`keyb.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset())

Comment: I tried your program, it doesn't work.. It keep asking me "No really. How old are you?"

Comment: @Spn Hm, works fine for me. It might be the delimiter - it's system dependent. You can also try `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: I have windows so \r\n works (\r works too). Thank you !

Comment: I've another question related to this. I'm now trying to do the same thing but with one character. Is there a solution to allow the user to enter one character (and only one, otherwise it will loop if he enter more than one) ? I can't find a solution since there is no hasNextChar() available.

And how can I do if I want to put restrictions in this character. For example if I only want a character that is a letter, or a character that can be either a letter or a special character (?!#..) etc ...

Answer (score 7):

You want to get the whole line. Use `nextLine` and check that for digits e.g.

```
String possibleAge = "";
do {
    System.out.println("How old are you ?");
    possibleAge = keyb.nextLine();
} while (!possibleAge.matches("\\d+"))
```

Comment: using a precompiled `Pattern` might be more efficient. As `String.matches` creates a new `Pattern` for every call

Comment: Only I’d leave out the initialization of `possibleAge` to the empty string. It’s not used anyway.

Comment: @OleV.V. Never mind, I'm an idiot. I am constantly surprised by how counter-intuitive Scanner's behaviour is. No wonder it stumps so many beginners.

Comment: @Spn `"\\d+"` is a regex. It's basically to check if a String matches a certain pattern/format. In this case `\\d` means digit (so `0-9`). The `+` means 1 or more. So it checks if the line entered by the user is exactly 1 or more digits, and nothing else. Small note (although a bit too advanced for now perhaps, but mainly added for other readers): `String#matches` adds an implicit leading `^`  and trailing `$` to regex-check the entire String.

Comment: @Spn You can always parse the String to an int with `Integer#parseInt` and the `\\d+` is a regular expression. The double \\ is for the java compiler. Also this is exactly the situation where you want to use a String.

Comment: Thank you, I have some questions : 

1) should I rather use string variables if I want to use the scanner in the future ? I feel that it's more secure and easier to control. And since keyb.nextInt cannot prevent the user to type whatever he wants, in what situation should I rather use it ?

2) I've never used "matches" so I will do some researches but can you explain what is "\\d+" ?

Edit : sorry I deleted my comment above because it was released too early

Comment: @Spn `[0-9]` is the same as \\d.

Answer (score 1):

```
String age = "11";
        if (age.matches(".*[^0-9].*")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid age");
        } else {
            System.out.println("valid age");
        }
```

If age contains other then digits then it will print invalid age.